# Menu Function and Classes in Python

Tags: python, function, class, menu

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name,):
        self.name = name

    def help (self):
        print (menu.keys())

    def name(self):
        print ("Hast du schon vergessen ? ")

c = Character
c.name = input("Wie heißt du denn ? ")
print ("Help, wenn du Hilfe brauchst")
menu ={"help":Character.help,
       "name":Character.name}

#This function allows you call up the main menu at any point in the game.  
while True :
  line = input(">")
  args = line.split()
  if len(args) < 4:
    Befehl_vorhanden = False
    for c in menu.keys():
      if args[0] == c[:len(args[0])]:
        menu[c](c)
        Befehl_vorhanden = True
        break
    if not Befehl_vorhanden:
      print ("ich verstehe dich nicht.")
```

Thanks to the help of the other stack overflow users, I was able to get my code running. I have created a menu for my game that can be called up at any point. However, it won't allow me to print any text. If I input "name" for example, it gives me.

*TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*

I have even tried using it as a basic function without my menu. However, I can't seem to get this code to work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: Which line produces the `TypeError`?

Comment: `c` is not an instance of `Character`; it's just another name for the class. `c = Character()`. There are a number of other problems with your code, though. Why is `Character` a class if none of its methods use `self`? Why does `help` depend on a free variable `menu`?

Comment: Hello Arn, after running the code by typing and your name in, you are able to call up the menu using "help". I want to call up the users name with "name", but I get an error in line 25 of my code.

Comment: I can't answer all of those questions to be honest. I am simply modeling my code on some things that I have seen and I am trying to understand the process behind. I am still relatively new at this. I appreciate your help though :).

Comment: What are you trying to do with `menu[c](c)`?

Comment: it allows me to call up the menu that I have created as a dictionary. I am still beginner. So, I am trying to modify legacy code:

( https://trinket.io/python/07c3a147aa).

I don't understand every single part of it, but works except for the fact that it doesn't printout functions that contain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
c.name = input("Wie heißt du denn ? ")
```

assigns the method Character.name to a string, hence you get 'str' object not callable on the line `menu[c](c)` because `menu[c]` is `Character.name`.

**Update:**

This program may be closer to the one you are looking for:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.namen = name

    def help (self):
        print (menu.keys())

    def name(self):
        print ("Hast du schon vergessen ? ", self.namen)

c = Character(input("Wie heißt du denn ? "))
print ("Help, wenn du Hilfe brauchst")
menu ={"help":c.help,
       "name":c.name}

#This function allows you call up the main menu at any point in the game.  
while True :
  line = input(">")
  args = line.split()
  if len(args) < 4:
    if args[0] in menu:
        k = args[0]
        menu[k]()
    else:
      print ("ich verstehe dich nicht.")
```

Note how I changed `__init__()` to perform: `self.namen = name` since your version *also* overwrites the declaration of `def name(self):`.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense. I changed it to a different function and it works. I guess I will have to find another way for it to print the person's name, but that is not super important. I just didn't think about trying something different. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Hey, that's awesome. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for helping me with my novice question. It try my best to solve things on my own, but it is kind of annoying getting a bunch of error messages and not making any progress.

Comment: You are not alone when StackOverflow is here to help you. You can keep asking questions here, just remember to narrow down the problem and include a full stacktrace (in the case of python) when you get one.

Comment: I will be sure to include n my next post and I hope that once I get better at python that I will be able to help others too :)

One last thing, could you explain to me what "args" does in this function ?  Like I said, this isn't all of my code. So, there are some parts of this that I don't really under

Comment: `args` is a list created by splitting up `line` at each space, so `"foo bar"` would become `["foo","bar"]`, although when you run the program and enter `"help"` for instance, then `args` would become a list of a single item: `["help"]` and `args[0]` is just `"help"`.

Comment: Ah okay, thank for you explaining that to me. I think that I'll play around with that a little bit to get a better hang of it !